# Access is Denied when connecting to remote computer using WMI from app under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, wmi, iis-express

I am getting `Access is denied` exception when I try to connect to a remote server using WMI through IIS (10.0).  This same code works fine through Visual Studio 2015 debug (IIS Express).  Obviously this is a permissions issue, however I cannot find anything definitive or even suggestive on the best way to approach this.

In my example, the client simply makes a POST call to the web service with credentials in the payload.  Then the service attempts to make a WMI connection getting the exception.  The remote server is not in a domain, and the credentials have been verified to have access to the given namespaces.

I'm running IIS 10, but have duplicated this with as low as IIS 7.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public ManagementScope Connect(Credentials creds, string path)
    {
        _creds = creds;
        _path = path;

        var conOpt = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
            EnablePrivileges = true,
            Username = _creds.Username,
            Password = _creds.Password,
            //Authority = $"ntlmdomain:{_creds.Domain}"
        };
        // virtualization\v2
        _scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{_creds.Server}\ROOT\{path}", conOpt);
        _scope.Connect();

        return _scope;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend to avoid WMI calls inside an application on IIS, due to the reason of possible security lacks.

I recommend to create a local windows service as command relay.
So you would call your local service and this service would execute the remote WMI call. The windows service then needs permission to execute the WMI command at the remote machine and you do not have to change the permission of your web application environment.

Just as information: on other platforms like Azure you are not allowed to change the security settings of your WebApp. Also the service / relay way would solve that requirement.

Comment: I was wondering how deep the permission issue would go.  And I'm glad you said something about Azure because that's where this will eventually end up.  I'm familiar with windows services, and I understand what you mean about making the service a command relay, I'm just not sure what that looks like implementation-wise.  Can you point me to a simple example or explain?  Thanks!

Comment: Azure Web Apps are running in a [sand box like environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). You cannot change make any changes to the application pool identity. For the service: just create a Windows Service with a WebAPI or something and create a (secured) communication over HTTP(S) of your WebApplication and your Windows Service and let the WIndows service communicate the remote stuff.
Workflow: WebApp > Windows Service > WMI Remote > Windows Service > WebApp. And another pro: you could replace the Windows Service very easily.

Comment: I implemented a ServiceStack service hosted in windows service.  Added the appropriate credentials for the service to run under and it works like a charm and I like the ability to switch out hosting mechanisms.  Thanks Ben!

Answer (score 0):

A common misunderstanding is that IIS Express is IIS. No.

IIS Express executes the code under your account. That means if your account has necessary permissions then the code runs fine.

However, IIS is purely a hosting service and your code runs under the worker process identity aka application pool identity. Review your IIS settings to understand what I mean.

Only if you change that identity to another suitable one or grant the account necessary permissions, the code can work after.

Note that a web app should not perform such tasks that requires lots of extra permissions and then they can be compromised and lead to serious security issues. That's why the other answer suggests you move the WMI calls to a dedicate Windows service.

I had a blog post a few months ago,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/04/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis/